# Hide/Show the application icon of the Windows taskbar (LabVIEW - WINAPI)

Tags: winapi, labview

I have an application created with LabVIEW and I need to show/hide the application icon on the Windows taskbar at run time.
I think that WINAPI can be used for this purpose and I tried to use the ShowWindow function (user32.dll)

ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_HIDE) -> hides the application window. The taskbar icon disappears for a second than re-appears.

ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWMINIMIZED) -> It simply minimizes the application window, so the taskbar icon remains

Comment: Even though it may be obvious to you, it certainly isn't to me: What is your question? Also consider taking the [tour] and visit the [help]. Reading [ask] is highly recommended as well.

Comment: Some basic websearch would tell you that the taskbar button is shown if and only if the associated window is visible. There are nuances, but that's the main way to hide the button. Make the window invisible.

Answer (score 2):

By default a "normal" visible un-owned window gets a taskbar button and the taskbar button is visible in every state except `SW_HIDE`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179(v=vs.85).aspx) also documents a couple of tricks you can use to override the button:

> The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the [`WS_EX_APPWINDOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) extended style. To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.
>
> ... If you want to dynamically change a window's style to one that does not support visible taskbar buttons, you must hide the window first (by calling `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE`), change the window style, and then show the window.

Another alternative is to use the [`ITaskbarList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, it gives you full control over your taskbar button.

Comment: The ITaskbarList can delete the taskbar icon but the window will get minimized to some unknown places like bottom right corner.

Comment: Do you have fix for that

Comment: @trickymind The owned window workaround is better but I guess you could try SetWindowPlacement. Bottom corner minimized is classic 16-bit Windows behavior.

Comment: But when using owned windows the Owned window always overlap the owner window, setWindowPos() is not working in that case, can you please provide a sample code, this is my current situation:https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/issues/9#issuecomment-904476672

Comment: Here is the video : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72641365/130594549-a0095b94-6318-4449-89aa-9d4213e02a30.mp4

Comment: i slow down the dwm animations to see what's happening

Comment: When using the owner method the owner should be 0x0 pixels so I don't really understand how it could overlap anything. You can also disable the animation: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121003-00/?p=6423

Comment: I am doing this all for the animation, it is indeed possible to create a window that can be like a shadow window, the setCompositionAttribute() uses similar method to avoid airspace issue, if you check the thumbnail of window which uses setCompositionAttribute(), you can see two windows. and they are perfectly synced together

Comment: `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` works perfectly.